# JQuery: How to do comparison of variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The script in question is posted below. The only line that is giving a problem is:

```
if(email1_text != email2_text )
```

And here is the rest of the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#email2').focusin(function() {
        var email1_text = $('email').val();
        var email2_text = $('email2').val();
        if(email1_text != email2_text )
            $('#email2_span').text('email addresses do not match');
    });
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Did you console.log() email1_text and email2_text to see what the output is?

Comment: Your selectors are wrong. `$('email').val(), $('email2').val();`, They need a class, ID, or attribute to properly "grab".

Comment: I believe it is a typo. Try `$('#email').val();` and `$('#email2').val();`

Comment: And `focusin` is the wrong time to be checking field values.

Answer (score 2):

To get elements by their IDs:

```
var email1_text = $('#email').val();
```

To get elements by their class names:

```
var email1_text = $('.email').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

These selectors are wrong. So no value will be returned.

```
var email1_text = $('email').val();
var email2_text = $('email2').val();
```

Should be something like:

```
$('#email') or $('.email')
```

Depending on what ***email*** element actually is. A class `.` or an id `#`.

**Example (not matching)**

http://jsfiddle.net/ue8bef92/3/

**Example (matching)**

http://jsfiddle.net/ue8bef92/5/